# Issues with JSONobject(index)

Tags: android, arrays, api, android-volley, jsonplaceholder

I have this array

```
 [{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"quis ut nam faciliset officiqui","completed":false}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":3,"title":"fugiat veniam minus","completed":false}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":4,"title":"et porro tempora","completed":true}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":5,"title":"laboriosam mkjakai","completed":false}]
```

I am using this Command

```
 Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: "+response.getJSONObject(0));
```

I am expecting this

```
 {"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false}
```

But irrespective of the integer index. I am getting this

```
  [{"userId":1,"id":1,"title":"delectus aut autem","completed":false}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":2,"title":"quis ut namfacilisetofficiqui","completed":false}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":3,"title":"fugiat veniam minus","completed":false}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":4,"title":"et porro tempora","completed":true}, 
 {"userId":1,"id":5,"title":"laboriosam mkjakai","completed":false}]
```

I am trying to figure out for hours. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is **response** a `JSONArray`?

Comment: JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        //Display the response
                        Log.d("TAG","Response: " + response.toString());//response is array. It gives array in string format.
                    }
                }

Comment: What you get seems like a normal array that contains some JSONObjects. Instead of treating 'response' as a JSONArray, you can try to treat it as a casual array that contains some JSONObjects. I'm not sure tho

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
  String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_id");
  ......
}
```